# Pyspark UDF for Dataframe vs RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

The Schema of my dataframe is:

```
root
     |-- _10: string (nullable = true)
     |-- _11: string (nullable = true)
     |-- _12: string (nullable = true)
     |-- _13: string (nullable = true)
     |-- _14: string (nullable = true)
     |-- _15: string (nullable = true)
     |-- _16: string (nullable = true)
     |-- _17: string (nullable = true)
     |-- _18: string (nullable = true)
     |-- _19: string (nullable = true)
     |-- _20: string (nullable = true)
     |-- _21: string (nullable = true)
     |-- _22: string (nullable = true)
     |-- _23: string (nullable = true)
     |-- _24: string (nullable = true)
     |-- _25: string (nullable = true)
     |-- id: long (nullable = true)
     |-- features: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
```

I want to do some operation using the features array and store the result in a new column: Prediction

```
def addPred(inp):
    global weights, bias
    for j in range(0,len(weights)):
        if j==0:
            out = sigmoid(np.dot(inp,weights[j]) + bias[j])
        elif j==len(weights)-1:
            out = softmax(np.dot(out,weights[j]) + bias[j])
        else:
            out = sigmoid(np.dot(out,weights[j]) + bias[j])

    if out[0]>out[1]:
        return -1*out[0]
    return out[1]
```

Using this UDF and the following code I'm trying to add a new column to the dataframe directly.

```
udf_addPred = udf(addPred, DoubleType())
test_data = test_data.withColumn('pred', udf_addPred('features'))
```

But it's giving me all kind's of errors.

- Sometimes 'not serializable error'
- Sometimes 'RDD is empty error'

But if I do the same operation using rdd map, it works using the following code

```
col_rdd  = test_data.rdd.map(lambda x: addPred(x.features))
```

- I tried debugging the issue myself but can't figure out the source of error
- Doing it the RDD way and then merging the column will require twice the computation
- Can someone please point out the error or suggest a better alternative?

EDIT:

Output for test_data.rdd.first():

```
Row(_10=u'Abu Dhabi Global Market', _11=u'Abu Dhabi Media Company', _12=u'Abu Dhabi Global Market (ADGM) BuildingADGM Square Al Maryah Island PO Box 111999', _13=u'Abu Dhabi Media P.O. Box 63', _14=u'Abu Dhabi', _15=u'Abu Dhabi', _16=u'Abu Dhabi', _17=u'Abu Dhabi', _18=u'United Arab Emirates', _19=u'United Arab Emirates', _20=None, _21=None, _22=u'557942700', _23=u'552544884', _24=u'www.adgm.com', _25=u'http://www.admedia.ae', id=4, features=[0.4782608695652174, 0.2592592592592593, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.14285714285714285, 0.0, 0.19999999999999996])
```

Weights and bias are corresponding things from Spark's Multilayer Perceptron

```
def extWeights():
    weights = []
    bias = []
    last = 0
    for i in range(0,len(model.layers)-1):
        curr = (model.layers[i]+1)*model.layers[i+1]
        weights.append(np.reshape(model.weights[last:last+curr],((model.layers[i]+1),model.layers[i+1])))
        bias.append(weights[i][model.layers[i]])
        weights[i] = weights[i][:model.layers[i]]
        last += curr
    return weights, bias
```

Comment: no need to merge after. Just modify your lamba to add the columns you need plus another columns with the result of your function.

Comment: test_data.rdd.take(1) ? can you show us the data a little bit ?

Comment: I am not sure you should use global variable. Try pass them as argument maybe.

Comment: what are `global weights, bias`?

Comment: do you realize in your `range` that you only keep the last version of out ? you do not need to do a for loop for that ...

Comment: @Steven there can be multiple layers, so the loop is to calculate the raw prediction thing for Multilayer Perceptron which isn't provided by default. The activation functions are different for different layers, I've implemented them accordingly

Comment: @RameshMaharjan added some edits for clarification

Comment: @Steven My mistake, your original suggestion works fine. And the problem is resolved for most part but is it possible to know why I'm getting an error while adding the column directly to dataframe?

Comment: what is model then?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan ann = MultilayerPerceptronClassifier(maxIter=1000, layers=nn_layers, stepSize=0.0001, seed=1000003),
model = ann.fit(train_data)

Comment: @user3908641 you have add all the information :)

Comment: @RameshMaharjan It's a wrk project so won't be able to do that. Also as I mentioned, using Steven's first comment I am getting the desired output. Just wanted to know why dataframe way doesn't work.

Comment: what are `train_data` and `nn_layers`?

Comment: train_data is dataframe of Row(features=DenseVector([0.4107, 0.2833, 0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.0, 0.1429, 0.1316]), label=0.0). For some rows, label would be 1. nn_layers is an array of how many layers there are in the perceptron.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution. RDD is working, therefore, bring back the cols you need in the lambda function :

```
col_rdd  = test_data.rdd.map(lambda x: addPred(x.features))
```

becomes

```
col_rdd  = test_data.rdd.map(lambda x: (x.neededCols, addPred(x.features)))
```

Comment: logically thinking, while creating the RDD, we're are basically copying 10 more attributes. Isn't this a bit bad?